# Выделение активной ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код которым я делаю выделение активных ссылок:

```
onload = function ()
{
  for (var lnk = document.links, j = 0; j < lnk.length; j++)
  if (lnk [j].href == document.URL) lnk [j] .style.cssText = 'background-color: #418CD0;';
}
```

Но он работает не так как хотелось бы. Дело в том, что я на главную страницу вывожу новости (При этом в навигации ссылка на Главную страницу выделяется), но когда перехожу на другую страницу `URL/?page=n` или когда захожу в новость `news/?id=n`, то подсветка Главная страница пропадает, но хотелось бы чтобы подсвечивалась, т.к новости и переход по страницам находятся на Главной странице.

Прошу помощи. Заранее вам огромное спасибо!

Comment: Вместо `document.URL` попробуйте использовать `document.URL.split(/[\?#]/)[0]`.

Comment: Посмотрите чему равно ваше lnk[j].href для такой ссылки.

Comment: скорее всего `var lnk = document.getElementsByTagName('a')` вместо `document.links`

Answer (score 1):

```
onload = function ()
{
var lnk = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i= 0; i < lnk.length; i++)
    if (lnk[i].href == document.URL) {
        lnk[i].style.cssText = 'background-color: #418CD0;';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onload = function ()
{
  var lnk = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i= 0; i < lnk.length; i++)
    if (lnk[i].href == document.URL.split(/[\?#]/)[0]) {
        lnk[i].style.cssText = 'background-color: #418CD0;';
    }
}
```

Спасибо